# SQL query about printing 3 tables at once

Tags: sql, db2

Code:

```
 select count(*) AS "NR_COMEDIES" from COMEDY

 select count(*) AS "NR_DRAMAS" from DRAMA 

 select count(*) AS "NR_TRAGEDIES" from TRAGEDY
```

I'm trying to print the count function of all 3 tables as one big table.

Where each table has its own column named from above. How can I make all 3 tables in one huge table?

I tried using union but that does not work.

Comment: Do you want to SUM the count of all the three table?

Comment: No, just print a table combined with columns NR_COMEDIES, NR_DRAMAS, NR_TRAGEDIES where each table shows the count of corresponding tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be `CROSS JOIN` should work for you

```
SELECT A.NR_COMEDIES,
       B.NR_DRAMAS,
       C.NR_TRAGEDIES
FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS "NR_COMEDIES"
        FROM   COMEDY) A
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS "NR_DRAMAS"
                   FROM   DRAMA)B
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS "NR_TRAGEDIES"
                   FROM   TRAGEDY) C
```

or Do a `Cartesian product` between all the queries

```
SELECT A.NR_COMEDIES,
       B.NR_DRAMAS,
       C.NR_TRAGEDIES
FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS "NR_COMEDIES"
        FROM   COMEDY) A,
       (SELECT Count(*) AS "NR_DRAMAS"
        FROM   DRAMA)B,
       (SELECT Count(*) AS "NR_TRAGEDIES"
        FROM   TRAGEDY) C
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted. I forgot about cross join, will have to review it.

Answer (score 2):

3 sub selects...

```
select
    (select count(*) from COMEDY) as "NR_COMEDIES",

    (select count(*) from DRAMA) AS "NR_DRAMAS",

    (select count(*) from TRAGEDY) AS "NR_TRAGEDIES"
from
    SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: Invalid DB2 SQL syntax.